# is it possible to connect to sql server 2008 using php and appserv on windows

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have sql server 2008 express installed, and I want to create application that connects to the db server using php, now i am developing under appserv on windows.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Use the [Microsoft SQL Server PHP Driver](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php) or Microsoft's [PHP Drivers for SQL Servers](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=20098)

Comment: thanks, i did used the  Microsoft SQL Server PHP Driver but the problem that my sql server uses windows authentication, and mssql_connect requests user name and password, how can i solve this?